# PCF8576 with VIM-878 LCD contrast problem

Tags: lcd

Hello I have circuit with LCD driver PCF8576 and VIM878 LCD
Vdd and VLCD for PCF I connected to 3.3V, but conrast is not good.
Only when I look at an angle, I can see well.

I'm using 4 backplanes
1/2 and 1/3 bias give this common effect.
Regards

Comment: Both Vdd and Vlcd are connected to 3.3V?

Comment: yes PCF8576 Vdd and Vlcd are connected to 3.3V

Comment: Could you share a schematic? It would be really usefull. I cannot understand what do you mean by 1/3 and 1/2 bias  to the backplanes.

Answer (score 1):

Vlcd must not be set to Vdd.

Use the datasheet to calculate how to set Vlcd correctly based on your backplane count and bias requirements.

Comment: Ok now I see the note information. I think best way to set good contrast is using potentiometer, but my device is battery powered